# Remove digits from a number so that the resulting number is largest and is divisible by 3

Tags: algorithm

Given a number with length N (1<=N<=100) consisting of digits only from 1 to 9. You have to remove at least 1 digit so that the resulting number is the largest and is divisible by 3.

Input:

Line 1: a single number t (1<=t<=100) which is the number of testcases.
The next t line(s): each line contains a number as described above.

Output: For each testcase, output a number which is the resulting number after removing some digits that satisfies the condition.
It is guaranteed that there is always a solution.

Input:

```
2
12324524
5321
```

Output:

```
1324524
531
```

A number is divisible by 3 only if the sum its digits is divisible by 3. So if the sum is not divisible by 3 then we can remove at most 2 digits. If the sum is divisible by 3 and no 1 or 2 digits can be removed, then we must remove 3 digits. Therefore, I will loop over every triple in the string, remove it, check if the sum after removing is divisible by 3 and update the maximum number. Here's my code for checking a number.

```
void check(string s)
{
    int n = s.size();
    string res = "0";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += s[i] - '0';
    bool f = 0, f1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((sum - (s[i] - '0')) % 3 == 0)
        {
            f = 1;
            string cur = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if(j != i) cur += s[j];
            res = max(res, cur);
        }
    }
    if (!f)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if ((sum - (s[i] - '0') - (s[j] - '0')) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    f1 = 1;
                    string cur = "";
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                        if (k != i && k != j) cur += s[k];
                    res = max(res, cur);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!f && !f1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int k = j + 2; k < n; k++)
                {
                    if ((sum - (s[i] - '0') - (s[j] - '0') - (s[k] - '0')) % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        string cur = "";
                        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++)
                            if (t != i && t != j && t != k) cur += s[t];
                        res = max(res, cur);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << res << '\n';
}
```

But the total time complexity of the check() function is O(n^4) where n is the length of the number and the number of testcases is t resulting in the total time complexity of the program to be O(t*n^4) which is too slow for t = 100 and n = 100 for every test case. Please give me an idea on improvement to this program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"for every test case"*: are you referring to some set of tests? What are they?

Comment: I meant to say that if the input had 100 testcases and each testcase there is a number with 100 digits then my program would run very slow.

Comment: Sum all the digits (without removing any digit!) of the number, only once. Take the result modulo 3. This gives you a number which is 0, 1 or 2. If it is 0, then the digit you remove must be a 0,3,6 or 9. If the result is 1, then the digit you remove must be 1,4 or 7. If the result is 2, then the digit you remove must be 2,5 or 8. That's it. No need to recheck any sum of digits after that.

Comment: @Stef sometimes you have to remove 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Indeed, but removing more digits is always worse, and happens only when no digits of the appropriate modulo are found at all, and the logic isn't very different in that case, just slightly more complex. I think it's worth solving the problem first under the assumption that only one digit needs to be removed, then once *that* is working properly, and only then, adapt the code to handle the case where more than one digit needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations and outline of algorithm:

- You could count the number of digits per "type", i.e. by whether they are 0, 1 or 2 (mod 3).
- Depending on the availability of digits of a certain type and the sum (mod 3), you can know how many digits you need to delete of each type.
- Then comes the task of selecting a digit (of the needed type) to delete. Here you should give precedence to deleting a digit that is not followed by a lesser digit, or when it is followed by equal digit(s), that those are not followed by a lesser digit. And if you find such digits, you should choose the leftmost of those.

  If you don't find such digit, then choose the rightmost digit that is of a needed type.
- Repeat the above as long as you have digits to delete.

Here is what it could look like:

```c
void removeDigits(string &s) // Pass by reference
{
    int n = s.size();
    // Count how many digits we have of each "type", ie. digit (mod 3)
    int counters[] = {0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counters[s[i]%3]++;
    }
    // Derive the modulo of the sum:
    int sum = (counters[1] + 2*counters[2]) % 3;
    // Derive how many we need to delete of each type:
    int need[] = {0, 0, 0};
    if (counters[sum]) {
        need[sum] = 1;
    } else if (sum) {
        need[3 - sum] = 2;
    } else if (counters[1] && counters[2]) {
        need[1] = need[2] = 1;
    } else {
        need[1 + !counters[1]] = 3;
    }
    // Remove a digit until we have reached the target
    int* good = new int[n];
    while (need[0] + need[1] + need[2]) {
        // Find out which digits are on a non-decreasing slope
        good[n-1] = 1;
        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            good[i] = s[i] < s[i+1] || s[i] == s[i+1] && good[i+1];
        }
        // Look for most interesting digit to delete
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n - 1 && !(need[s[i]%3] && good[i])) {
            i++;
        }
        // If we didn't find a "good" one, then just take the rightmost needed
        while (!need[s[i]%3]) {
            i--;
        }
        // Delete this one...
        need[s[i]%3]--;
        s.erase(i, 1);
        n--;
    }
    delete[] good;
}

int main() {
    string tests[] = {"12324524", "5321", "85252", "147147"};
    for (string s : tests) {
        cout << s << " => ";
        removeDigits(s);
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

NB: as '0' has an ASCII value that is a multiple of 3, I didn't bother to do `- '0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it runs perfectly. Maybe I should think of other solutions instead of focusing on brute-force.

Answer (score 1):

Removing as few digits as possible is most important. You can figure out how many digits have to be removed as follows:

```java
    int[] count = new int[3];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : digits) {
        sum += i;
        count[i % 3]++;
    }
    sum = sum % 3;
    int target = (3 - sum) % 3; // the sum of the digits modulo 3 has to equal target
    if (count[target] > 0) {
        return removeDigits(1, target, digits);
    } else if (target == 0 && count[1] > 0 && count[2] > 0 || // (1 + 2) % 3 = 0
               target == 1 && count[2] > 1 || // (2 + 2) % 3 = 1
               target == 2 && count[1] > 1) { // (1 + 1) % 3 = 2
        return removeDigits(2, target, digits);
    } else if (target == 0) { // only case where it makes sense to remove 3 digits
        return removeDigits(3, target, digits);
    } else { // have to remove all digits
        return 0;
    }
```

Now we have to know to remove which x digits. You already know exactly the modulo of the digits you have to remove (when you have to remove 3 digits all of the digits of the whole number have the same modulo and if you have to remove 2 digits with different modulo just try both orders and compare).

1. Remove digits from left to right with the following properties (as long as possible): they have the correct modulo and the digit following it is greater than the digit itself. If the following digit is the same compare with the following one and so on.
2. If there are no or not enough digits removed by the strategy above then just remove first digits from the right with correct modulo.

Basically first try to remove digits that make the resulting number greater (compared to just removing the last digit) and we want this to happen as early as possible, so we go from left to right, but if that's not possible we want to have the least damage and remove the first from the right to have the least impact on reducing the resulting number.

In conclusion this is solvable in O(n).